# Проблема с наследованием font-weight на заголовки и другие элементы

Tags: html, css

Подключил шрифт из google fonts

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

Затем начал настраивать глобальные шрифты

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100 !important; 
}
```

И по какой-то причине на большинство элементов типа заголовков, элементов списка и т.д font-weight, который я как бы переопределил все равно перебивается браузерными свойствами font-weight на этих элементах. Даже !important не помогает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Никаких reset и nozmalize, библиотек или бутсрапа не подключено.

Comment: То есть заголовки, например как были со своим font-weight, так и остались после моего определения. Неужели font-weight не наследуется пр каких-то условиях??

Answer (score 0):

Свойство *font-weight*  наследуется, но всегда приоритетнее правило, указанное текущему тегу, т.е. то которое, в данном случае указанное заголовкам. Для решения, Вам просто нужно указать теги и нужные им правила в своем файле стилей `h1 {font-weight: 100; }`